# floating a div with texts inside a parent div

Tags: css, html

I have a `<div>` that I want to float inside a parent `<div>`. The parent div contains some HTML entries like `texts,  images, tables`

If I make the `HTML` like this then it gives the result I want

```
<div class="parent-div">
<div class="child-div">
Child div content
</div>

Parent div HTML content
</div>
```

Result

```
+---------- parent div --------------+
|Parent HTML content... +-----------+|
|...................... | child div || 
|...................... | child div ||
|...................... +-----------+|
|....................................|
|....................................|
+------------------------------------+
```

My problem is I don't want to put the second (child) div content before the parent content.

I want to make the HTML like this

```
<div class="parent-div">
Parent div HTML content

<div class="child-div">
Child div content
</div>
</div>
```

and if I make the HTML like the one show above it renders the child div after the complete parent HTML

Result for the above

```
+---------- parent div --------------+
|Parent HTML content.................|
|....................................| 
|....................................|
|....................................|
|                       +-----------+|
|                       | child div ||
|                       | child div ||
|                       +-----------+|
+------------------------------------+
```

I'm using these styles for the child div `<div style="width:200px; float:right;">`

Is it possible to float the `child div` with the parent texts if I post the `child div` after the parent texts ends

Comment: Why does the order matter for you?

Comment: have you tried to add a margin-top to the child div??

Comment: because the child div has huge content and it is secondary in the page. The parent content is the primary and I want it to appear first when the page renders or better to say for search engines.

Comment: @bingjie2680 you mean negative values for the child div right? if I do that it wraps with the parent content, the output becomes something like `position:absolute` and more than that the parent content doesn't have fixed height

Comment: @anuj, ok, never mind, i think it will overlap.

Comment: @bingjie2680 yes you are right, it is overlapping :(

Comment: What is if you use this markup instead: `<article><aside>child content</aside>real content</article>` to gain semantics and SEO?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle or something? the ascii drawing are cool but hard to inspect on:)

Comment: @insertusernamehere WOW you just told me something I never knew. Looks like these `<article>` and `<aside>` tags (may be many more to go) are introduced in HTML5 because CSS can't do what I want :) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos here it is http://jsfiddle.net/uJZhu/

Comment: Yeah, there are also `header`and `footer` for example. Take care that you need something like **[html5shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)** to get it to work in IE8, all other modern browsers have it out of the box. ;)

Comment: While ASCII art is nice, they are several free [**online mockup generators**](http://speckyboy.com/2011/02/23/10-completely-free-wireframing-and-mockup-tools/) to use too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `float`, just `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:0`: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2QVX8/21/

**EDIT:** As the comment below:
Set the original box with absolute position, then create a floated fake element as a space for the original box: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2QVX8/22/

Comment: This is just the same result I (drawn above) don't want. I want the child div to wrap with texts as it does when inserted before the parent content.

Comment: This what I tried so far. Set the original box with absolute position, then create a floated fake element as a space for the original box. I don't have any idea: [http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2QVX8/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2QVX8/22/)

Comment: what you did is excellent and exactly what I wanted. Can you please do a little more effort and say how can I get it work with `.parent:after` also. `.parent:after` is creating the position but I'm not able to position it like `.parent:before`